# T-SQL Use CTE to initialize variables inside a view

Tags: t-sql, variables, view, common-table-expression, declare

I need to create a view - it is composed by five UNION ALL statements. The difference between each statement is that the data is filter by different period:

For example:

```
SELECT  RecordName
       ,CASE
        WHEN RecordDate > DATEADD(WEEK,-1,GETUTCDATE()) THEN 'This week'
        END
UNION ALL
SELECT  RecordName
       ,CASE
        WHEN RecordDate > DATEADD(WEEK,-2,GETUTCDATE()) THEN 'Previos week'
        END
SELECT  RecordName
       ,CASE
        WHEN RecordDate > DATEADD(Year,-1,GETUTCDATE()) THEN 'Year ago'
        END
```

Then I am creating a pivot using the view.

Anyway, the "date" condition is calculate in more complex way. I am using GETUTCDATE() function too and this will return different value any millisecond.

That's why I want to use a CTE expression in order to initialize all date condition variables or to do the calculations one time only in the CTE, and then to use this date conditions in the SELECT-UNION clause.

The problem is, I am not able to join the information from the CTE with the SELECT statement below and when I try to use the date conditions directly (without join) it is not working ("Error  - Invalid Column name").

This is a example of what I am trying to do:

```
WITH DatePeriods(ThisWeek,LastWeek,MonthToDate,QuarterToDate,YearToDate) AS
(
    SELECT  DATEADD(WEEK,-1,GETUTCDATE())  AS ThisWeek
           ,...                            AS LastWeek
           ,...                            AS MonthToDate
           ,...                            AS QuarterToDate
           ,DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETUTCDATE())  AS YearToDate
)

SELECT  RecordName
       ,CASE
        WHEN RecordDate > ThisWeek THEN 'This week'
        END
UNION ALL
SELECT  RecordName
       ,CASE
        WHEN RecordDate > LastWeek THEN 'Previos week'
        END
SELECT  RecordName
       ,CASE
        WHEN RecordDate >YearToDate THEN 'Year ago'
        END
```

Comment: You have to use the CTE in the from clause of each query. You can do it with a `cross apply`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's work perfect.

Please, post your answer in order to mark the question as closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the CTE in the from clause of each query. You can do it with a `cross apply`.

```
WITH DatePeriods(ThisWeek,LastWeek,MonthToDate,QuarterToDate,YearToDate) AS
(
    SELECT  DATEADD(WEEK,-1,GETUTCDATE())  AS ThisWeek
           ,...                            AS LastWeek
           ,...                            AS MonthToDate
           ,...                            AS QuarterToDate
           ,DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETUTCDATE())  AS YearToDate
)

SELECT  RecordName
       ,CASE
        WHEN RecordDate > ThisWeek THEN 'This week'
        END
FROM YourTable 
  CROSS APPLY DatePeriods 
UNION ALL
SELECT  RecordName
       ,CASE
        WHEN RecordDate > LastWeek THEN 'Previos week'
        END
FROM YourTable 
  CROSS APPLY DatePeriods 
SELECT  RecordName
       ,CASE
        WHEN RecordDate >YearToDate THEN 'Year ago'
        END
FROM YourTable 
  CROSS APPLY DatePeriods
```